# .slideUp() not working as intended

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

i have an icon that triggers both the effect of slide up and slide down but after sliding down it doesn't work anymore if i press the same icon again.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('.subcat-row').hide();

    $("body").on("click",'.drop-subcat', function () {

        if($(this).children('i').attr('class','fa fa-toggle-down drop-down-icon')){
            $(this).closest('.category-row').siblings('.subcat-row').slideDown(500);
            $(this).children('.drop-down-icon').attr('class', 'fa fa-toggle-up drop-down-icon');
        } else if( $(this).children('i').attr('class','fa fa-toggle-up drop-down-icon') ){
            $(this).closest('.category-row').siblings('.subcat-row').slideUp(500);
            $(this).children('.drop-down-icon').attr('class', 'fa fa-toggle-down drop-down-icon');
        }
    });
});
```

here is the jsfiddle i made..

http://jsfiddle.net/vnbtfc92/

Comment: I don't think your `if` clauses are doing what you think they do. (They are setting the classes, not testing them.) I promise you `slideUp` works exactly as intended; the problem is in your logic.

Comment: Bootstrap has a collapse plugin that already does this; is there a reason you aren't using it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you are having is with this

```
.attr('class','fa fa-toggle-up drop-down-icon')
```

this sets the class attribute to `'fa fa-toggle-up drop-down-icon'`, so using in an if statement is not right (i.e. doesn't return boolean). I think you mean to test the class so use hasClass instead (which returns a boolean, true or false), something like

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('.subcat-row').hide();

$("body").on("click",'.drop-subcat', function () {

        if($(this).children('i').hasClass('fa fa-toggle-down drop-down-icon')){

            $(this).closest('.category-row').siblings('.subcat-row').slideDown(500);
            $(this).children('.drop-down-icon').attr('class', 'fa fa-toggle-up drop-down-icon');

        }else if($(this).children('i').hasClass('fa fa-toggle-up drop-down-icon')){

            $(this).closest('.category-row').siblings('.subcat-row').slideUp(500);
            $(this).children('.drop-down-icon').attr('class', 'fa fa-toggle-down drop-down-icon');

        }

    });
});
```

If fact working with classes, as it appears you want to add a class to indicate it is down, and the same for up, just use the standard jQuery class functions i.e. `addClass`,`hasClass`,`removeClass` or `toggleClass`, much easier than using `attr`

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('.subcat-row').hide();

$("body").on("click",'.drop-subcat', function () {   
        var childi =  $(this).children('i');
        if(childi.hasClass('fa-toggle-down')){    
            $(this).closest('.category-row').siblings('.subcat-row').slideDown(500);    
        }else if(childi.hasClass('fa-toggle-up')){    
            $(this).closest('.category-row').siblings('.subcat-row').slideUp(500);    
        }
       childi.toggleClass('fa-toggle-up fa-toggle-down');    
    });
});
```

or for variable caching, small code point of view, taking advantage of ternary operator and javascript method invocation via strings and square brackets, try the following

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('.subcat-row').hide();

$("body").on("click",'.drop-subcat', function () {   
        var self = $(this),
            childi = self.children('i'),
            slideDirection = childi.hasClass('fa-toggle-down') ? "slideDown":"slideUp";
        self.closest('.category-row').siblings('.subcat-row')[slideDirection](500);
        childi.toggleClass('fa-toggle-up fa-toggle-down');    
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this: `$(this).children('i').attr('class','fa fa-toggle-down drop-down-icon')`, but save the state with [`$(this).data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/).

The easiest way to compare if some class is set for an element is [`$(this).is('.className')`](http://api.jquery.com/is/).

But I'd use `.data()`.